# Count the number of unique words and occurrence of each word

Tags: c++

CSCI-15 Assignment #2, String processing.  (60 points)  Due 9/23/13

You MAY NOT use C++ string objects for anything in this program.

Write a C++ program that reads lines of text from a file using the `ifstream getline()` method, tokenizes the lines into words ("tokens") using `strtok()`, and keeps statistics on the data in the file.  Your input and output file names will be supplied to your program on the command line, which you will access using `argc` and `argv[]`.

You need to count the total number of words, the number of unique words, the count of each individual word, and the number of lines.  Also, remember and print the longest and shortest words in the file.  If there is a tie for longest or shortest word, you may resolve the tie in any consistent manner (e.g., use either the first one or the last one found, but use the same method for both longest and shortest).  You may assume the lines comprise words (contiguous lower-case letters [a-z]) separated by spaces, terminated with a period.  You may ignore the possibility of other punctuation marks, including possessives or contractions, like in "Jim's house".  Lines before the last one in the file will have a newline ('\n') after the period.  In your data files, omit the '\n' on the last line.  You may assume that the lines will be no longer than 100 characters, the individual words will be no longer than 15 letters and there will be no more than 100 unique words in the file.

Read the lines from the input file, and echo-print them to the output file.  After reaching end-of-file on the input file (or reading a line of length zero, which you should treat as the end of the input data), print the words with their occurrence counts, one word/count pair per line, and the collected statistics to the output file.  You will also need to create other test files of your own.  Also, your program must work correctly with an EMPTY input file – which has NO statistics.

Test file looks like this (exactly 4 lines, with NO NEWLINE on the last line):

> the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
>   now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party.
>   all i want for christmas is my two front teeth. 
>   the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.

Copy and paste this into a small file for one of your tests.

Hints:

Use a 2-dimensional array of char, 100 rows by 16 columns (why not 15?), to hold the unique words, and a 1-dimensional array of ints with 100 elements to hold the associated counts.  For each word, scan through the occupied lines in the array for a match (use `strcmp()`), and if you find a match, increment the associated count, otherwise (you got past the last word), add the word to the table and set its count to 1.

The separate longest word and the shortest word need to be saved off in their own C-strings.  (Why can't you just keep a pointer to them in the tokenized data?)

Remember – put NO NEWLINE at the end of the last line, or your test for end-of-file might not work correctly.  (This may cause the program to read a zero-length line before seeing end-of-file.)

This is not a long program – no more than about 2 pages of code

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

void totalwordCount(ifstream &inputFile)
{
    char words[100][16]; // Holds the unique words.
    char *token;
    int totalCount = 0; // Counts the total number of words.
    // Read every word in the file.
    while(inputFile >> words[99])
    {
        totalCount++; // Increment the total number of words.
        // Tokenize each word and remove spaces, periods, and newlines.
        token = strtok(words[99], " .\n"); 
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " .\n");
        }
    } 
    cout << "Total number of words in file: " << totalCount << endl;
}

void uniquewordCount(ifstream &inputFile)
{
    char words[100][16]; // Holds the unique words
    int counter[100];
    char *tok = "0";
    int uniqueCount = 0; // Counts the total number of unique words
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    {
        uniqueCount++;
        tok = strtok(words[99], " .\n");
        while(tok != NULL)
        {
            tok = strtok(NULL, " .\n");
            inputFile >> words[99];
            if(strcmp(tok, words[99]) == 0)
            {
                counter[99]++;
            }
            else
            {
                words[99][15] += 1;
            }
            uniqueCount++;
        }
    }
    cout << counter[99] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    char inFile[12] = "string1.txt";
    char outFile[16] = "word result.txt";

    // Get the name of the file from the user.
    cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
    cin >> inFile;

    // Open the input file.
    inputFile.open(inFile);

    // If successfully opened, process the data.
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(!inputFile.eof())
        {        
            totalwordCount(inputFile);
            uniquewordCount(inputFile);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I already took care of how to count the total number of words in the file in the `totalwordCount()` function, but in the `uniquewordCount()` function, I am having trouble counting the total number of unique words and counting the number of occurrences of each word. Is there anything that I need to change in the `uniquewordCount()` function?

Comment: I'd strongly advise to find a better C++ class! There is no point to being thought how to program C when the goal is to learn C++! This statement is outright ridiculous: "Remember – put NO NEWLINE at the end of the last line, or your test for end-of-file might not work correctly." Instead of giving you arcane advice your teacher should rather find out how to properly read data in C++!

Comment: This doesn't look so good. You're a long way from understanding what you are doing, and 95% of this code should be thrown away. It isn't even close to correct. I think you really need to sit down with someone whose got the time to go through this exercise with you. You'll get more understanding from interacting with a real person than you would from this forum. This forum is only really good at answering specific questions, it's not really a substitute for proper teaching.

Comment: I second what Dietmar says, it doesn't help that you've been given such a crappy little exercise.

Comment: I've already mentioned this on the same Code Review post: you're still including `<string>` even when told that you're not supposed to use `std::string`.  Did you add it by accident, or is this an act of rebellion? ;-) But anyway, I agree with the others.  With these kinds of instructions, your instructor is pretty much teaching you how to program in C.

Comment: Also, I feel that "put NO NEWLINE at the end of the last line, or your test for end-of-file might not work correctly" is an indication that `eof()` is okay to use for this assignment.  I hope I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Heh, "You MAY NOT use C++ string objects for anything in this program." - because that stuff is only for the *real* world. And this is the second time I've seen this said-same instructor note to not put a trailing newline in the input file, because it makes parsing the file "harder". So much for robust coding practices. Drop the class and take it from someone that has a clue.

Answer (score 4):

This program contains several issues which are to be considered harmful! To prevent bad software being created based on entirely nonsensical assignments like the above, here are a number of hints:

1. **Always** test the stream for success **after** reading from it. Using `in.eof()` to determine if the stream is in a good state does **not** work! One of the problems is that you will get an infinite loop if the stream goes bad for a different reason than end of file, e.g., failure to correctly parse a value (this will set `std::ios_base::failbit` but not `std::ios_base::eofbit`.
2. Reading to a fixed size `char` array `a` using `in >> a` without having set up limits for the number of characters to be read is the C++ way to spell `gets()`! If you really think that using `in >> a` is the right way to (see next item), you **absolutely need to** set up the array's width, e.g., using `in >> std::setw(sizeof(a)) >> a`. You still need to check that this extraction was successful, of course.
3. From the looks of it, your teacher wants you to actually use `std::istream::getline()` to read the array, e.g., using `in.getline(a, sizeof(a))` (which, of course, needs to be checked for success).
4. Note that the formatted input, i.e., `in >> a` already tokenizes the stream being received by spaces! There is no need to faff about with `strtok()` after that.
5. Once you have consumed a stream, it is consumed. Assuming the characters don't come from a file but rather from something like standard input, you also can't rewind the stream to read it again. I'd think you want to tokenize the values once and use them for both purposes.
6. This is more of a sidenote: after you created a stream, its nature should be entirely immaterial for the processing of the stream's content (although, e.g., for string streams you might want to eventually collect the result using the `str()` member): implement your stream processing functions in terms of `std::istream` rather than `std::ifstream`!

Since you have a concrete question ("Is there anything that I need to change in the uniquewordCount() function?"): yes, everything! Throw away this function entirely and rethink what you need to do. Basically, the structure of the functionality should be along the lines of

```
char buffer[100];
while (in.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
    // tokenize buffer into words
    // for each word check if it already exists
    // if the word does not exist, append it to the array of known words and set count to 1
    // if the word exists, increment the count
    // determine if the word is shorter or longer than the shortest or longest word so far
    // if it is the case, remember the word's index or a pointer to it
}
```